# My logo text sticks to the left of my page eventhough i have it set to centered

Tags: html, css

So I want my navbar to be so that the Work and Press elements are aligned on the left side, the YORK logo text in the center and the About and Contact elements on the right. So far i've managed to make it so that the left and right works, but for some reason i cant seem to find my York logo sticks to the left side.

I tried to change what classes i gave the flex property to. I tried to change the way i set up the html as well.

```css
body {
  font-family: europa, sans-serif;
  padding-left: 3vw;
  padding-right: 3vw;
}

header {
  display: flex;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
}

.nav-left-press,
p {
  color: #b3b3b3;
  margin-left: 1vw;
}

.nav-right-about,
p {
  color: #b3b3b3;
}

.nav-right-contact,
p {
  color: #b3b3b3;
}

.nav-left {
  text-align: left;
}

.nav-right {
  text-align: right;
  position: absolute;
  right: 3vw;
}

.nav-center-logo {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <nav class="nav-left">
    <div class="nav-left-work">Work</div>
    <div class="nav-left-press">Press</div>
  </nav>
  <div class="nav-center-logo">YORK</div>
  <nav class="nav-right">
    <div class="nav-right-about">About</div>
    <div class="nav-right-contact">Contact</div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: As you can see in the answers given below, there is a couple of ways you can do this. Besides those answers I see you have 2 ```<nav>``` elements, I would suggest you to make those divs and put a nav around the whole navbar. As you said in your post it is all the same navbar, so to keep it readable, and also for other reasons, it is best to put it al in 1 ```<nav>...</nav>``` element.

Comment: Also, to give you a bit of extra information, the ```,``` in css is used to seperate selectors with eachother. In your code that means you are styling the ```<p>``` element 3 times (which can be done in 1). There is 3 instances in your css where you give it ```color: #b3b3b3;``` and one where you give it ```margin-left: 1vw;```. Those can be combined easily as ```p {margin-left: 1vw; color: #b3b3b3;}```  If you were trying to further specify the selector, read how you can do this here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did two editions to your css, remove two declarations that was broken your position in `.nav-right {}` declaration and add `justify-content: space-between;` to `header {}` declaration, let me know if is working  for you now.

```css
body {
  font-family: europa, sans-serif;
  padding-left: 3vw;
  padding-right: 3vw;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
}

.nav-left-press,
p {
  color: #b3b3b3;
  margin-left: 1vw;
}

.nav-right-about,
p {
  color: #b3b3b3;
}

.nav-right-contact,
p {
  color: #b3b3b3;
}

.nav-left {
  text-align: left;
}

.nav-right {
  /* text-align: right;
  position: absolute; */
  right: 3vw;
}

.nav-center-logo {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
      <nav class="nav-left">
        <div class="nav-left-work">Work</div>
        <div class="nav-left-press">Press</div>
      </nav>
      <div class="nav-center-logo">YORK</div>
      <nav class="nav-right">
        <div class="nav-right-about">About</div>
        <div class="nav-right-contact">Contact</div>
      </nav>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
body {
  font-family: europa, sans-serif;
  padding-left: 3vw;
  padding-right: 3vw;
}

header {
  display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
}

.nav-left-press,
p {
  color: #b3b3b3;
  margin-left: 1vw;
}
.nav-right-about,
p {
  color: #b3b3b3;
}
.nav-right-contact,
p {
  color: #b3b3b3;
  margin-left: 1vw;
}

.nav-left {
  text-align: left;
}

.nav-right {

}

.nav-center-logo {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
      <nav class="nav-left">
        <div class="nav-left-work">Work</div>
        <div class="nav-left-press">Press</div>
      </nav>
      <div class="nav-center-logo">YORK</div>
      <nav class="nav-right">
        <div class="nav-right-about">About</div>
        <div class="nav-right-contact">Contact</div>
      </nav>
    </header>
```

I've added a justify-content: space-between to your header.

Removed the position absolute from your nav-right.

Hope this helps.